# Import all tables from a database into my data flow task

Tags: sql-server

How could I get all the tables from one of databases I have in just one SQL instruction

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all tables in a database you can query the sys.Tables. Simply:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables;
```